# Pass data in DurandalJS to other view

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I'm developing a `SPA webapplication` with `DurandalJS`, but I don't understand something.

Let's say I have `page 1` and `2`. On `page 1` there is a modal that creates a entity in the `database` with `BreezeJS` and gives back a key (that was generated in the database).

I want to pass this fetched key and then go to my second page, page 2. I know how I can do this when I put it in the url

```
http://localhost:60312/#/page2?orderid=2&repairorder=2
```

But this is not the way for `Durandal`, or is it? A user can enter a number of his own with al consequences!

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the only seamless way to pass parameters between view models in a Durandal app is to use the normal hash-based url parameters.
In you example, you can define a router that takes a orderId and repairOrder parameters, then your url would look something like this:  `http://localhost:60312/#/page/2/2`

This is best option, if your data isn't too sensitive.  Leave the navigation parameters in the open, and handle the values with care in the second view model.  In other words, design your view model so that it can properly handle any values - even if a user directly modifies a parameter value, your view model should be able to handle it correctly.

It can be advantageous to be able to set url parameters directly, but you do have to be careful to ensure the integrity of the values before consuming them.

However, if you need to hide the parameters, you do have some different options:

**Encryption:** Use an encryption library like tea.js, and encrypt the value before adding it as a parameter value for navigation.  Then, of course, decrypt it on the second page before using it.  This allows Durandal's `router` navigation to work normally, while preventing users from supply their own values.

If you really need to prevent users from entering their own values, and you can bear the overhead of a few extra KB's, this is a good approach as long as you only need to pass a few parameters.

**Shared data model:** Use a singleton model which is shared between the two view models.  This model can be manually `required()` as needed, and essentially serves as a repository for the application state that is shared between one or more view models.
This works fine, but it's kind of like having a big global variable - it can get messy if it's overused.

**Modify VM directly:** *(Only for singleton view models)* 
Manually `require()` the second view model and set its properties before navigating to it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot in the right direction. I was wondering is it also possible to add extra data in the router it self when it goes from view A to B like say put it in the routeinfo.settings?

Comment: Unfortunately encrypting the url parameters won't prevent users fron changing values as they want. They can still use your encryption library themselves and pass whatever encrypted data into the url as they wish. Even if they couldn't, they could still pollute your viewmodel easily.

Comment: @JaniHyytiäinen, you are correct, and it's probably worth pointing that out.  However, it's also worth realizing that all these methods are subject to user manipulation - with the app running in JS, *there's no way to fully prevent any possibility of users modifying data and/or execution flow on the client side*.  That's why it is *imperative* to always ensure that any critical parameter validation or business logic is executed on the server side before trusting data from the client.  Client-side logic is optional, server side isn't.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add something to the very good @Joseph Gabriel answer. In durandal you can do this:

```
router.map( url: 'page2/:orderid/:repairorder',
            name: 'Page2',
            moduleId: 'viewModels/page2');

http://localhost:60312/#/page/2/2
```

But also, you can do this:

```
router.map( url: 'page2',
            name: 'Page2',
            moduleId: 'viewModels/page2');

http://localhost:60312/#/page2?orderid=2&repairorder=2
```

You don't nedd to specify all the parameters that you are pasing. Yo can get this parameters from the input of the active method.

```
var activate = function(context) {
  console.log(context.orderid);
  console.log(context.repairorder);
}
```

Sometimes the second solution can be more appropriated if you want that the user can store the url to repeat a query only copping that in the browser.