# Durandal: I have data in the shell - how do I push it to a viewmodel?

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

In my `shell.js`, there's an action that can be called to collect some data from an API endpoint  (a list of tickets).  Once I have this data, I `router.navigateTo("purchase"),` which is a valid route.

I need to pass this data into the viewModel now.  Is there any standard approach to doing this with DurandalJS, or do I have to look into some kind of pub/sub mechanism?

One solution (that I've implemented for now) is to just use window - in `shell.js`, once the data service call is complete, I say `window.tickets = dataFromService.`  Then within the "purchase" vm, I work off of `window.tickets`.  This feels dirty and I'm interested in what a proper solution would look like with durandal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Durandal's philosophy not the shell should retrieve the data. Instead the purchase vm should do it in its `activate` callback (http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/). Just make sure to return a promise from `activate` if ticket collection is an `async` operation.

Here's an example of that pattern, where `getListCollection` can either returns a cached result (sync) or an async result and is therefore wrapped in a $.when(), which always returns a promose.

http://www.spirit.de/demos/metro/durandalsp3/index.html#/lists

```
var activate = function () {
    var self = this;
    var webUrl = L_Menu_BaseUrl;

    self.webUrl(webUrl);

    logger.log('Activatíng List View', null, 'list', true);

    return $.when(spdata.getListCollection({ webUrl: webUrl })).then(function (result) {

        // Access to detail list information through listInfo[listName]
        self.listInfo = result;
        self.lists(createListVMs(result));

        return true;
    });
};
```

**Updated based on comment**:
If you have to retrieve data in shell to make decisions there are a couple of options.

- You might consider converting the purchase vm into a widget as in Durandal 1.2
  only widgets can have additional data passed in.
- As an alternative
  create a `global` AMD that returns a singleton and is shared between
  shell and purchase.
- Third option would be to declare purchase as
  dependency in shell and modify purchase directly.

See @Joseph Gabriel [Pass data in DurandalJS to other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355960/pass-data-in-durandaljs-to-other-view/16358297#16358297) for details.

Comment: Thanks Rainer.  Most of my vms handle data like this, but in this particular case, data is collected from the shell vm.  Some operation happens in shell.js that gives me the data that the purchase vm needs.  I can't collect this data from the purchase vm because the result of that data determines whether or not the purchase vm is loaded.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you again.  What kind of issues can using window for this introduce?

Comment: You mean other than the obvious `;-)`? e.g. https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478 or http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-essentials-of-writing-high-quality-javascript/

Comment: In regards to the singleton option that @RainerAtSpirit mentioned, Durandal's router module is useful in that regard.  I've used it to store flash style messages across routes.  Just attach an arbitrary object to router and then remove it after it's been used.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use custom events (pub/sub style) to pass arbitrary data between viewModels.

```
app.trigger('my:custom:event', message);

app.on('my:custom:event').then(function(message){
    //do something with the payload
});
```

Check out [the documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/) for more details.