# Durandal: pass parameter to view request url

Tags: javascript, .net, durandal

I know this question might trigger some reactions of the type "View-model separation is good". So please be aware that I am aware of that :).

So, when activating a route, Durandal obtains a view by doing a very simple get request, just using something like "view.html" in the get url.

Question: is it supported to add a parameter to the url? So as to have: "view.html?id=4".

I know it's not the point but I want to do it anyway. Why? Because currently, an important part of the js code happens in the viewAttached method. I am using a js library for adding stuff to the page, that needs access to the dom. So when reaching the page, one can see modifications taking place, and it's not nice to see the page changing like that. So I'd prefer that stuff to happen on the server, using a .Net control.

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can find all the information that you need in this other question: [Pass data in DurandalJS to other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355960/pass-data-in-durandaljs-to-other-view/16361725#16361725)

Comment: Thanks for your answer jvr, but it doesn't seem to work. I did as suggested in your other answer, and passed the id in the url. This works fine, but still, when getting the view from the server, durandal issues a get request that only contains "view.html", and does not pass the id along with it.

Comment: I think Im gonna give up on this. The only I managed to achieve what I want is by changing text.js and checking window.location.href to find my id. But the views are of course not retrieved everytime. So since this is totally counter intuitive and agains Durandal philosophy, I'll just pass on that one. Thanks anyway.