# DurandalJS - Parameters to the MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, durandal, single-page-application

I'm starting to develop SPA with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Durandal.
I customized the durandal view locator to call my MVC controller and use '.cshtml' files as my views. Doing that, it's possible to use Razor syntax and do something like this:

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
{
   // Code
}
```

However, I need to pass parameters to my Controller to load different data and then pass it as the Model of the view. For example, I have a list of dashboards, and when the user click to open I have to pass the dashboard's id to load its structure.
My route is configured like this:

```
var routes = [
            { route: 'dashboard/:id', moduleId: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard' }];
```

The activate function of the dashboard's viewmodel receive the parameter, but I need to send the id to the MVC controller.
I've been looking for some way to do that, but I didn't find anything yet. There's this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290850/durandal-pass-parameter-to-view-request-url) that is similar, but it's not answered.
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks! :D

Comment: One of the questions I've always had about packaging Durandal as a NuGet MVC package is why would you have both a client-side and server-side MVC. I see several questions on here pertaining to how they step on each others toes. Any reason for using both?

Comment: I'm using durandal to give a more fluid application for my users. It helps me at the navigations between my other views (i.e. login, menu, configuration, etc). But I have to generate a dynamic HTML, depending on which dashboard is being opened. The easiest way to do that is using the razor syntax. I can do a foreach and call js components or partials views to render my controls.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell

```
define(['plugins/http', 'plugins/router'], function(http, router){

  // make call to build routes based on authenticated user (implement to return an array in 'routes')
  http.get('URL_for_RoutesCurrentUser')
      .then(function(result) {
        $.each(result.routes, function(key, value){
          router.routes.push(value);
        });
      });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I'm busy right now, but will give a try later.